# Spring Security, No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered

Tags: spring, безопасность, java

В приложении spring mvc нужна авторизация в закрытом разделе /admin

Конфиг web.xml после добавления Spring Security:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-secutiry.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user authorities="ROLE_USER" name="guest" password="guest" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Запросы к приложению приводят к выкидывание сервером ошибки

```
HTTP Status 500 - No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

type Exception report

message No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:251)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.8 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.8
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

Comment: Странно, сейчас работает.

Я пробовал добавлять эту строку, томкат выкидывал ошибку

27-May-2014 22:09:40.255 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(81)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
27-May-2014 22:09:40.256 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(81)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что у вас тут немного напутано с настройками: чтобы всё работало должно быть два контекста -- `WebApplicationContext`, который создаётся диспетчер сервлетом, и `ApplicationContext`, который создаётся `ApplicationListener`-ом и в котором находится конфигурация Spring Security.

Сейчас же у вас:

- contextConfigLocation, который должен инициализировать listener указывает на файл с настройками контекста для диспетчер сервлета (и более того, там опечатка в названии)
- у диспетчер сервлета не указано где искать конфиг
- в файле который предназначается как конфиг для диспетчер сервлета содержатся настройки Spring Security

Скорее всего, после исправления этих проблем у вас всё ещё не будет работать эта связка. Как минимум, потому что:

- диспетчер сервлет определен раньше чем сервлет Spring Security (а значит до Spring Security запросы не будут доходить)
- в маппинге у вас указано, что все страницы требуют аутентификации (а это значит, что вы не сможете открыть страницу логина, ведь она также будет требовать аутентифицированного пользователя)